# AngularJS a service is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

This current code when ran returns `TypeError: Services.updateUserData.set is not a function`

**Controller**

```
Services.updateUserData.set($rootScope.user);
```

**Services.js**

```
this.updateUserData = function() {
        return {
            set: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'api/data/',
                    data: {'data': data},
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},                 
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The code below works but I would much rather have a get and set function within `updateUserData` so that I am not duplicating work.

**Current Code**
**Controller**

```
Services.updateUserData($rootScope.user);
```

**Services.js**

```
this.updateUserData = function() {
    console.log(data);
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'api/data/',
        data: {'data': data},
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},                 
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Call like this `Services.updateUserData().set($rootScope.user);`. `updateUserData` is a function.

Comment: @Chandermani what there be a way to get it cut down to `Services.updateUserData.set($rootScope.user);`?

Comment: updateUserData should be an object then `this.updateUserData={set:function(){}}`

Comment: @Chandermani stick it down as an answer and I will accepr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateUserData` is a function and hence there is no property called `set`. The option is either convert it to object

`this.updateUserData={set:function(){}}`

or invoke it

`Services.updateUserData().set($rootScope.user);`

before accessing `set`